# How do I find out the current UnhandledExceptionMode

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I know that you can change the UnhandledExceptionMode by using Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(...). How do I find out what the current UnhandledException mode is?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to programatically determine this. [in managed code public APIs]

As I remember the default can depend on the .NET framework version, i.e. 2.0 would silently kill off threads where an exception occurs and is unhandled (other than the main thread), whereas later versions would throw the exception correctly to the main thread/cause the app to crash so nothing is lost.